# implementing shuffle functioning in a music player

Tags: random

This was asked in an interview

```
    "What is the most efficient way to implement a shuffle function in a music
     player to play random songs without repetition"
```

I suggested link-list approach i.e. use a link-list, generate a random number and remove that item/song from the list ( this way , we ensure that no song is repeated )

then I suggested bit vector approach but he wasn't satisfied at all.
so what according to you is the best approach to implement such a function?

Comment: I'm not sure what the most efficient solution is, but you should probably start by mentioning the most obvious: shuffle the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no perfect answer, I guess this sort of questions is aimed to start a discussion. Most likely your interviewer was wanting to hear about [Fisher–Yates shuffle (aka Knuth shuffle)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Here is brief outline from wiki:

> 1. Write down the numbers from 1 through N.
> 2. Pick a random number k between one and the number of unstruck numbers remaining (inclusive).
> 3. Counting from the low end, strike out the kth number not yet struck out, and write it down elsewhere.
> 4. Repeat from step 2 until all the numbers have been struck out.
> 5. The sequence of numbers written down in step 3 is now a random permutation of the original numbers.

You should mention its inefficiencies and benefits, how you could improve this, throw in a few lines of code and discuss what and how you would test this code.

Answer (score 3):

Below are some implementations. I also had difficulties during the interview but after the interview I saw that the solution is simple.

```
public class MusicTrackProgram {

// O(n)  in-place swapping
public static List<MusicTrack> shuffle3(List<MusicTrack> input) {

    Random random = new Random();

    int last = input.size() - 1;

    while (last >= 0) {

        int randomInt = Math.abs(random.nextInt() % input.size());

        // O(1)
        MusicTrack randomTrack = input.get(randomInt);

        MusicTrack temp = input.get(last);

        // O(1)
        input.set(last, randomTrack);
        input.set(randomInt, temp);

        --last;

    }

    return input;

}

// O(n)  but extra field
public static List<MusicTrack> shuffle(List<MusicTrack> input) {

    List<MusicTrack> result = new ArrayList<>();

    Random random = new Random();

    while (result.size() != input.size()) {

        int randomInt = Math.abs(random.nextInt() % input.size());

        // O(1)
        MusicTrack randomTrack = input.get(randomInt);

        if (randomTrack.isUsed) {
            continue;
        }

        // O(1)
        result.add(randomTrack);
        randomTrack.isUsed = true;

    }

    return result;

}

// very inefficient O(n^2)
public static List<MusicTrack> shuffle2(List<MusicTrack> input) {

    List<MusicTrack> result = new ArrayList<>();

    Random random = new Random();

    while (result.size() != input.size()) {

        int randomInt = Math.abs(random.nextInt() % input.size());

        // O(1)
        MusicTrack randomTrack = input.get(randomInt);

        // O(1)
        result.add(randomTrack);

        // O(n)
        input.remove(randomTrack);
    }

    return result;

}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<MusicTrack> musicTracks = MusicTrackFactory.generate(1000000);

    List<MusicTrack> result = shuffle3(musicTracks);

    result.stream().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.getName()));
}
```

}

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can use link list and a queue for implementing a song search in mp3 player
We can extend this to following functionalities:

1. Add a new song
2. Delete a song
3. Randomly play a song
4. Add a song in play queue

Suppose initially we have 6 songs stored as link list
Link list has 2 pointers : start and end

totalSongCount=6

**Randomly play a song:**
We will generate a random number between 1 to totalSongCount. Let this be 4
We will remove the node representing song 4 and keep it after end pointer
we will decerement the totalSongCount (totalSongCount--).

Next time random number will be generated between 1 to 5 as we have decremented the totalSongCount , we can repeat the process

**To add a new song**, just add it to link list and make it as head pointer(add in beginning)
increment totalSongCount (totalSongCount++)

**To delete a song** , first find it and delete it 
Also keep a track whether it is after end pointer , if it is not just decerement the totalSongCount (totalSongCount--)

**The selected song can have two option:**
Either play at that moment or
Add to a playlist (Seperate queue)

Answer (score 0):

```
I think below solution should work 

class InvalidInput extends Exception{
    public InvalidInput(String str){
        super(str);
    }
}

class SongShuffler{

    String songName[];
    int cooldownPeriod;
    Queue<String> queue;
    int lastIndex ;
    Random random;

    public SongShuffler(String arr[], int k) throws InvalidInput{
        if(arr.length < k)
            throw new InvalidInput("Arr length should be greater than k");
        songName = arr;
        cooldownPeriod = k;
        queue = new LinkedList<String>();
        lastIndex = arr.length-1;
        random = new Random();
    }

    public String getSong(){
        if(queue.size() == cooldownPeriod){
            String s = queue.poll();
            songName[lastIndex+1] = s;
            lastIndex++;
        }
        int ind = random.nextInt(lastIndex);
        String ans = songName[ind];
        queue.add(ans);
        songName[ind] = songName[lastIndex];
        lastIndex--;
        return ans;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).